# How to add inputs values generated with a loop using jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

How can I get the values of my inputs generated with a jQuery loop in PHP?

I have two inputs, that are generated by a loop and I need to get those two inputs with jQuery to use as validation in our thesis.

The code is:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i <5 ; $i++) {
    echo "$i.   
        <input class='text$i' type='text' name='text$i'>
        <input class='text$i' type='text' name='text$i'>
        </br></br>";        

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(<?php echo "'.text$i"?> ).each(function(){
                $(this).keyup(function(){
                    calculateSum();
                });
            });
        });

        function calculateSum() {
            var sum = 0;
            $(<?php echo "'.text$i'";?>).each(function() 
            {
                if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0)
                {
                    sum += parseFloat(this.value);
                }

                $('#sum').html(sum.toFixed());
            });
        }
    </script>

    <?php
    echo"<label>Total:&nbsp;</label><span id='sum'>0</span>";
    echo "</br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var calculateSum = function () {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.class1').each(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length !== 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

        $('#sum').html(sum.toFixed());
    });
};


$('.class1').each(function () {
    $(this).keyup(function () {
        calculateSum();

    });
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/scnCw/)

Comment: if i change the class i can't get the value of two inputs.

Comment: is there conflict between code of jquery and variable of php because I insert php varible like this  $(<?php echo "'.class$i'"?>).each(function () { code in jquery and the thing is not working.